# how to make particular column editable for copy in datagridview of devexpress in c#?

Tags: c#, datagridview, devexpress

I have devexpress datagridview that have 10 columns with first column as Name which is non-editable but the user should be able to copy the cell content(Name).

Comment: check this link , the last comment might be useful :  https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q256225

Comment: Also, add the approaches you have already tried to get better response in SO.

Comment: Am added like gridViewBatches.Columns["Batch No"].ReadOnly = true; Error 71 Property or indexer 'DevExpress.XtraGrid.Columns.GridColumn.ReadOnly' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

Comment: doesnt looks like that to me : https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/A281

Comment: I find following solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void gridViewBatches_ShowingEditor(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e) 
{
    GridView view = sender as GridView;

    if (view.FocusedColumn.FieldName == "Batch No") //Editable true
    {
        e.Cancel = false;
    } else //Other column editble false
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to change `ReadOnly` or `AllowEdit` options of your columns.

Other solution is to use the `ShowingEditor` event of the view and disable cell editing via code using the event handler's `e.Cancel` parameter.

**Here is the code snippet:**

```
//Disable updating on the entire grid
uGrid1.DisplayLayout.Override.AllowUpdate = DefaultableBoolean.False;

// Disable the first column in the first band
ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns[0].CellActivation = Activation.Disabled;

// Disable the first cell in the grid
uGrid1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Activation = Activation.Disabled;

ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns[0].CellActivation = Activation.Disabled;
```

**Update :**

Following solution works for Amol as confirmed in comments, including here for others benefit.

```
private void gridViewBatches_ShowingEditor(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e) 
{
    GridView view = sender as GridView;

    if (view.FocusedColumn.FieldName == "Batch No") //Editable true
    {
        e.Cancel = false;
    } else //Other column editble false
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Am added like gridViewBatches.Columns["Batch No"].ReadOnly = true;
                            Error 71 Property or indexer 'DevExpress.XtraGrid.Columns.GridColumn.ReadOnly' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

Comment: @Amol I've placed code sample/usage, try and let me know if there are any issues.

Comment: Thanks Hari.But this code snipeet is not working.If u have another solution  please share with mi. Thank You!!

Comment: private void gridViewBatches_ShowingEditor(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            GridView view = sender as GridView;

            if (view.FocusedColumn.FieldName == "Batch No")//Editable true
            {
                e.Cancel = false;
            }
            else//Other column editable false
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
        }

Comment: Yes This is the solution.